# Why Autowired bean not creates new instance but does loaded from context?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-bean

I have simple scheduler.

```
public class MailSendScheduler {

    @Autowired 
    MailCollector mailCollector;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * *")
    public void call() throws Exception {
        log.info("Method executed " + new Date());

        taskExecutor.initialize();

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                mailCollector.setText(Integer.toString(i));
            taskExecutor.execute(mailCollector);
        }
    }   
}
```

My config looks like this:

```
<bean id="mailCollector" class="ge.ddrc.school.mails.MailCollector" scope="prototype" >
            <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    </bean>
```

Mail Controller is **runnable** class, and I log the integers in run() method.

```
@Component
public class MailCollector extends Thread {
  public void run(){ log.info() }
}
```

What do you think what will be result? It should be from 0 to 14 is not it? But not it looks like this:

```
2,2,4,5,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14.
```

It seems that mailController is Singleton. I think it is not creating new bean. **But WAIT** , If I write this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/mail-config.xml");

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            MailCollector  mailCollector=(MailCollector) context.getBean("mailCollector");
            mailCollector.setText(Integer.toString(i));
            taskExecutor.execute(mailCollector);
        }
```

the output is like this: 1,2,3,4,5,8,9,6,7,10,15,13,14,12,11.` And it is correct too! why this happens?

Comment: Because you don't understand `prototype`. That scope will create a new instance of a bean as soon as one is requested. In the first sample you basically have a singleton in the second you get a new instance for each cal to getBean. Although you shouldn't create a context yourself but you could simply inject it into the current bean by implementing `ApplicationContextAware`.

Comment: Or you can `@Autowire` the `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 0):

That's how Spring prototype scope works.

Prototype scope means each **reference** gets its own instance (each `@Autowired`, each `context.getBean()`).

You would have to use a custom scope and a scoped proxy to get a new instance for each iteration of your loop. That's pretty advanced stuff. It's probably easier to create your own factory to get a new instance for each iteration.

Comment: In theory shouldn't a `scoped-proxy` also work? Although each method call would probably result in a new instance that way. You want a scope between thread and visibility or something.

Comment: I meant scoped proxy, sorry - but he'll need a custom scope, right?

Comment: Probably, not sure what happens if you put `<aop:scoped-proxy />` on a prototype scoped bean. I would expect a new instance for each method call on the proxy.

Comment: I don't think so: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection In any case he's calling 2 methods on each iteration - the setter and `run()`.